# Is it possible to use LibGDX with MoltenGL

Tags: java, ios, opengl, libgdx, metal

Now that Apple has deprecated OpenGL and OpenGL ES in favor of their proprietary Metal Graphics API, I am trying to find a long term solution to still use Java for cross platform game development.

I have been using LibGDX and would like to continue doing so but it uses OpenGL.

Libgdx uses LWJGL for Dekstop platforms and a fork of RoboVM for IOS, which is why I am unsure if it will work or not.

My question is would i be able to use something like [MoltenGL](https://moltengl.com/) with LibGDX for Mac and IOS or is there some other Java alternative?

Comment: It seems like this should be possible. Essentially, you'd need to add a new backend similar to the existing RoboVM [GL ES 2.0 backend](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-robovm/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/iosrobovm/IOSGLES20.java), then generate a JNI wrapper/[implementation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/jni/iosgl/iosgl20.cpp) that calls into MoltenGL instead of the platform GL library.

Comment: @warrenm would there be any easier way, like an existing framework for java that supports metal already, or something that can convert whatever RoboVM exports out to Metal?

Comment: I can't think of an easier way. It seems like libGDX is pretty opinionated about using a GL-like API, so writing a Metal backend (even using the Metal bindings already provided by RoboVM) would be a significant amount of work. MoltenGL does the bulk of that work for you (at least on iOS).